# Php mail notification run with no error but cannot function

Tags: php, email

my current php mail cannot be send out (*no error, all can run well, but only cannot send out notificant email*), and my code as attached.

[image]

```html
if (isset($_POST["normal"])) { // check if normal leave form was submitted
  $insert = "INSERT INTO leave_applications (type, date_from, date_to, reason, days, submitted_on, notice, status, users_id)
  VALUES ('$type', '$ifrom', '$ito' , '$reason1' ,'$days', '$date', 'normal', 'Pending', '$id')";

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From:" . "limwenwei1997@gmail.com". "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Cc: wenwei.lim@screamingtomatoes.com" . "\r\n";

$message = '<p><strong>This is strong text</strong> while this is not.</p>';

  $admin = "wenwei.lim@voodoocomms.com";
  $applicant = "limwenwei1997@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Tomato Portal: New Leave Submission";




  mail($admin,$subject,$message,$headers);




} else {
  $insert = "INSERT INTO leave_applications (type, date_from, date_to, days, submitted_on, notice, status, users_id)
  VALUES ('$type', '$ifrom', '$ito' ,'$days', '$date', 'short', 'Pending', '$id')";
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From:" . "limwenwei1997@gmail.com". "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Cc: wenwei.lim@screamingtomatoes.com" . "\r\n";

$message = '<p><strong>This is strong text</strong> while this is not.</p>';

  $admin = "wenwei.lim@voodoocomms.com";
  $applicant = "limwenwei1997@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Tomato Portal: New Leave Submission";




  mail($admin,$subject,$message,$headers);

}
```

Please someone help to reach me out,k thanks

Comment: The "insert to database" function run well, only mail doesn't function but dun have any error.

Answer (score 0):

Some time server administrator disables `mail` function for preventing user to send spam.